# JavaFX 8 - fx:include PropertyNotFoundException: Property "customEvent" does not exist or is read-only

Tags: javafx-8, fxml

I am getting the following exception during runtime. The sub fxml is a Combobox that is included in Main fxml. The goal is to wire the Combobox selection change event to refreshing a table in Main using customEvent="#testSystemSelectAction" in the fx-include tag

What am I missing?

Many thanks!

### Exception:

```
Caused by: com.sun.javafx.fxml.PropertyNotFoundException: Property "customEvent" does not exist or is read-only.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:348)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processPropertyAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:325)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processInstancePropertyAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:235)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:767)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
... 67 more
```

### Sub fxml controller:

```
public class SystemComboboxUIController extends BaseController {
...
    private ObjectProperty<EventHandler<ActionEvent>> propertyCustomEvent = new SimpleObjectProperty<EventHandler<ActionEvent>>();

    public ObjectProperty<EventHandler<ActionEvent>> customEventProperty() {
        return this.propertyCustomEvent;
    }

    public void setCustomEvent(EventHandler<ActionEvent> customEvent) {
    this.customEventProperty().set(customEvent);
    }

    public EventHandler<ActionEvent> getCustomEvent() {
    return this.customEventProperty().get();
    }
    ...
```

### Main fxml:

```
...
<fx:include source="SystemComboboxUI.fxml" fx:id="testSystemComboboxUI" customEvent="#testSystemSelectAction"/>
...
```

### Main controller:

```
...
@FXML 
public void testSystemSelectAction(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
    populateTableview();
}
...
```

Comment: The type of the object instantiated by the `<fx:include>` element will be the type of the root node of the included FXML file; i.e. it will be some kind of `Node` subclass. That type does not define `customEventProperty()` (that method is defined in the controller class, not in the node class). Consider using an [FXML-based custom component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components) for this instead.

Comment: Thanks @James, the distinction between `fx:include` and custom component makes sense. As this is not really a custom component but rather a subset (like JSF Facelets), I was hoping `fx:include` would work as above since that is cleaner. I will opt for plan B --- stick with fx:include and specify a handler in Main controller `testSystemComboboxUIController.testSystemCombobox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {...`